# Measure Earth Magnetic Field using Hall Effect

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, electrostatics, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-circuits

[image]
This is about Hall Effect from this youtube video at [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Scpi91e1JKc&ab_channel=jordi3736). The voltage across a metal will change based on the strength of the magnetic field. I am wondering whether this will be accurate in reading small magnetic field such as the earth's magnetic field to point to the NORTH. From my knowledge, since the earth magnetic field is small and weak, it is very difficult to read on a multimeter, so perhaps we can amplify that small voltage to a big voltage by using op-amp.

Is this a possible solution and what metal should i use for building it because I am trying to make my own DIY magnetometer?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia - Hall effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect) the Hall voltage is
$$V_H=\frac{IB}{nte}$$
where $I$ is the current, $B$ is the magnetic field strength,
$n$ is the charge carrier density, $t$ is the thickness
of the slab, and $e$ is the elementary charge.

So, in order to get a larger Hall voltage $V_H$
you want to use a material with a lower charge carrier density $n$.
That means you will not use a metal, but a semiconductor
(e.g. doped silicon, or gallium-arsenide).
You can even buy ready-made [Hall effect sensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect_sensor)
for less than 2 US-dollars.

And using an op-amp to amplify the still small voltage
definitely makes sense.
But there are also Hall sensors available coming with an
an op-amplifier already within the same integrated circuit.

Comment: It's important to realize (if making your own sensor) that the carrier density impacts the current $I$ as well. In fact, if the Hall voltage is expressed in terms of the bias voltage, the $n$ factor gets canceled. That said, high sensitivity Hall sensors do use semiconductors partly because of their high carrier mobilities.